# Is it possible to draw outside the client window using OpenGL

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

Just like to add a bit question similar to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232727/win32-how-to-draw-outside-my-window). Is there anyway I could do to draw outside the client window using OpenGL without any native commands to be used? or is this beyond OpenGL previleges?

Other ways I could think of is to draw a sub window and remove the built in borders and button on it, then draw what I wanted there?

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: I suppose it's not the work of opengl, and display managers on various systems restrict opengl's drawing with the window's borders. Maybe a portable solution can be found in some GUI framework (like Qt).

Comment: @lisyarus do u haz te link?