# Active window screenshot with Python PIL and windows API: how to deal with rounded corners?

Tags: python, windows, screenshot, python-imaging-library, rounded-corners

For [this project](http://code.google.com/p/quickscreenshots), I'm taking screenshots with the Windows API (to deal with multi-screens) and convert it to a PIL image; then I add a shadow around the window if wanted.

My problem is, the screenshot is actually of the window's rectangle; meaning I capture the background behind it around rounded-corners and I don't want that. I googled quite a bit and found docs and tuts around transparency, and I'm guessing I should find a way to get the shape of the window in order to make it a mask that I would apply to the (rectangle) image i've got. But I found noway to get that mask. Could any one help?

Below is my code:

```py
hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

l, t, r, b = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
w = r - l
h = b - t

hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)
saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

saveDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (w, h),  mfcDC,  (0, 0),  win32con.SRCCOPY)

#add cursor
if showcursor:
    curFlags, curH, (curX, curY) = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()
    saveDC.DrawIcon((curX, curY), curH)

#load into PIL image
"""http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199497/image-frombuffer-with-16-bit-image-data"""
bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
im = Image.frombuffer(
    'RGB',
    (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
    bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
saveDC.DeleteDC()
mfcDC.DeleteDC()
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwndDC)

return im
```

Below is a slightly magnified screenshot of a window above a blue background:

[image]

As you can see there are blue corners that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I still couldn't find a solution. Anybody?

Comment: In fact, I have never found a software handling window-capture successfully, even for SnippingTool.exe offerred by MicroSoft.  Try Cutting 2 pixels, or making that 2 pixels of pure black/white.   if u want cut the exactly shape , reading MS doc: window corner shape is defined in system.RadiusX/RadiusY    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle.radiusy.aspx#Y0

Comment: Similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224220/win32-how-to-make-drop-shadow-honor-non-rectangular-layered-window

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [Edge detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) algorithm (f.e. Prewitt or Sobel) to detect the window edge, you only need to set the alpha channel to the pixels between the image limits and the window edge limits.